# Open/Close Div Overlay

Tags: jquery, html, overlay

My current script is a little broken. Clicking on the link in the table successfully creates my div overlay. Then I close my div and click on another link and the div overlay opens again the close button stops working.

I'm guessing the problem is that that DOM doesn't recognize my empty divs again after I use "replaceWith".

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<table id="tableBin" border="0">
    <tr>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>description</th>
    </tr>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="clip/location/A001C012_111129_R1VL.mov">A001C012_111129_R1VL.mov</a></td>
        <td>Adipiscing elit. Fusce bibendum, leo non.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="clip/location/A001C012_111130_R1VL.mov">A001C012_111130_R1VL.mov</a></td>
        <td>Consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce bibendum, leo non.</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>

</table>

<div id="overlay">
    <div id="blackOut" class="hide">
        <div id="box" class="hide">
            <div id="controls" class="hide"><a href="#"><img border="0" alt="close" width="25px" hieght="25px" src="images/close.png"></a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $("#tableBin a").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr("href");
        var video = jQuery('<embed width="640" height="375" ShowControls=1 src="'+url+'" /></embed>');

        $('#blackOut').removeClass("hide").addClass("blackOut");
        $('#box').removeClass("hide").addClass("box");
        $('#controls').removeClass("hide").addClass("controls");
        $('#box').append(video);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

http://jsfiddle.net/aramk/WesNb/2/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#tableBin a.video").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var url = $(this).attr("href");
            var video = $('<embed width="640" height="375" ShowControls=1 src="'+url+'" /></embed>');

            $('#overlay').removeClass("hide");
            $('#blackOut').removeClass("hide").addClass("blackOut");
            $('#box').removeClass("hide").addClass("box");
            $('#controls').removeClass("hide").addClass("controls");
            $('#video-container').removeClass("hide").html(video);
        });

        $("#close-button").click(function(e) {
            $('#overlay').addClass("hide");
            $('#video-container').addClass("hide").html("");
            return false;
        });
});
​
```

I wasn't sure if you wanted to replace the playing video or not, so I've added a container which has its contents replaced with the loaded video on each click.

Also, your original code replaced everything when close was clicked - this is very destructive and unmaintainable. Changing anything in the HTML would mean changing everything in the JS - in a string - which is very messy.

Comment: Sorry Aram, I screwed up. The div does open again, but the close button stops working. :-/

Comment: Are #close-button and #video-container new elements or just ids on the img and video?

The problem I seem to be having is $('#video-container').addClass("hide").html(""); is deleting my close button image.

Comment: close-button is just an id for the existing close button. video-container is a new element to contain only the element tag. That line shouldn't delete the close button unless the close button is inside the video-container, which it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("#box img").on("click", function(e) {
        $('#overlay').html('<div id="blackOut" class="hide"><div id="box" class="hide"><div id="controls" class="hide"><a href="#"><img border="0" alt="close" width="25px" hieght="25px" src="images/close.png"></a></div></div></div>');
    });
```

instead

Comment: Oops, I need to make a correction Tte link works again, but the close button stops working after the first time.